# Error handling for ASP based sites and forms

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, error-handling

I'm working on a asp based (not .net) site, which spans about 400 odd pages... Now, throughout the site there're ASP and VBScript errors, such as:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: 'Cdate'

/MySite/page.asp, line 71

(The above happened when I put in characters into a 'date' field. I know its VBScript in this case, but I get plenty all over.)

Now, I know I can avoid this scenario with client side validation (jQuery for example), but when such things do happen, how do I code up a default 'error' page? You hit the error, and instead of showing you the above, you get redirected to a generic 'error' page?

I've looked up some of this, and found the ASP 'On Error Resume Next' thing, but I haven't found any viable examples. Each one is tailored to a specific error (like dividing 5 by 0), and I really don't want to code up like 400+ potential error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create custom error pages, via IIS.  I'm not sure what version you're running, etc - but this should give you a good jumping off point. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224070

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response... This worked out good enough, where IIS lets me point to a specific page should the server throw up a http error... Now, I need to get to debugging (aka - kill me now) the vbscript and validation errors... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You add following code in top in your page.

```
    <% on error resume next%>

.
..
....
```

(Other code is above instead of point(.))

Then you add

```
<% if err then
response.redirect("err.page?code="&err.code)
end if%>
```

And you define error message in your generic error page according to error number.

Answer (score 0):

if you ask same question for client side. You can try and catch code block for possible code clock that will can throw.

For examle

```
<script language="text/javascript">
try
  {
//Code that will can throw error is here. 
  }
catch(err)
  {
 document.href.location="genericerrorpage.asp?err=" + err.code;


  }
}

</script>
```